# Add values in two rows together and group

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, sum

[SQL Server Management Studio 2016, TSQL]

Could you help me with this SQL please?

I have the below rows:

```
Account Reference | Balance
      100291         -301
      100291          157
      102388          203
```

However I want to add the balance of the first two rows together and group by Account reference like the below:

```
Account Reference | Balance
      100291         -144
      102388          203
```

For your reference, the code for this is below:

```
SELECT
    RB.AccountReference,
    RB.CurrentBalance
FROM SB_RentAccountBalances_V RB
    LEFT JOIN RentAccounts RA ON RB.AccountReference = RA.ID
```

Could someone please give me advice on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    RB.AccountReference,
    sum(isnull(RB.CurrentBalance,0))
FROM SB_RentAccountBalances_V RB
    LEFT JOIN RentAccounts RA ON RB.AccountReference = RA.ID
group by
     RB.AccountReference
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, it is not clear that a `JOIN` is needed:

```
SELECT RB.AccountReference, SUM(RB.CurrentBalance) as CurrentBalance
FROM SB_RentAccountBalances_V RB
GROUP BY RB.AccountReference;
```